# Rank on each group without using derived table

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

```
AccountNo           Account Name         Transaction time             Transaction Amount
A01                 Name 1               01-01-2016 04:00:00          5000
A01                 Name 1               01-01-2016 07:30:00          3500
A01                 Name 1               01-01-2016 09:30:00          3500
A01                 Name 1               01-01-2016 12:00:00          6500
A01                 Name 1               02-02-2016 06:00:00          4000
A01                 Name 1               01-02-2016 08:30:00          8000
A01                 Name 1               01-02-2016 09:30:00          8000
A02                 Name 2               05-01-2016 04:00:00          2000
A02                 Name 2               05-01-2016 07:30:00          8500
A02                 Name 2               08-02-2016 06:00:00          1000
A02                 Name 2               09-02-2016 08:30:00          9000
```

I need a query without using derived table to get the records which has latest transactions for each account. Query should support `Oracle` or `TERADATA`.
Using Derived table I am able to solve it as below:

```
SELECT a.accountno, 
       a.account_name, 
       a.transaction_time, 
       a.transaction_amount 
FROM   acct_details a, 
       (SELECT accountno, 
               Max(transaction_time) AS Transaction_time 
        FROM   acct_details 
        GROUP  BY accountno) b 
WHERE  a.accountno = b.accountno 
   AND a.transaction_time = b.transaction_time;
```

Thanks for Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why without Derived Table?

In Teradata there's QUALIFY, but it's no Standard SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM   acct_details 
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY accountno 
                     ORDER BY transaction_time DESC) = 1;
```

In Oracle you need a Derived Table:

```
SELECT a.accountno, 
       a.account_name, 
       a.transaction_time, 
       a.transaction_amount,
FROM
 ( 
    SELECT a.accountno, 
           a.account_name, 
           a.transaction_time, 
           a.transaction_amount,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY accountno 
                        ORDER BY transaction_time DESC) as rnk
    FROM   acct_details a
 ) a
WHERE rnk = 1
```

You might also try Oracle's MAX/KEEP:

```
SELECT a.accountno, 
       MAX (a.account_name) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.transaction_time desc) , 
       MAX(a.transaction_time), 
       MAX (a.transaction_amount) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.transaction_time desc)     FROM  acct_details a
GROUP BY a.accountno
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using an inline view like so:

```
SELECT a.accountno, 
       a.account_name, 
       a.transaction_time, 
       a.transaction_amount 
FROM   (SELECT accountno, 
               account_name, 
               transaction_time, 
               transaction_amount, 
               Max(transaction_time) OVER (PARTITION BY accountno) AS max_transaction_time 
        FROM   acct_details) a
WHERE  a.transaction_time = a.max_transaction_time;
```

This will work on Oracle and I think it should also work on Teradata.

I assume here that when you say you want to avoid a derived table, you mean you want to avoid joining the table to itself.

Comment: Both having same alias 'a' ? Are you sure?? This should give an error.

Comment: *Inline View* = *Derived Table*

Comment: @TechBytes whoops, I'd forgotten to delete the table from the from clause before posting my answer. I've removed it now - thanks!

Comment: @dnoeth I've added a comment explaining my assumption re. what the OP meant by avoiding a derived table.

Comment: Ups, you're correct (after edits), sorry. But it's still a Derived Table :-)

Answer (score -1):

try this query:

SELECT  [Transaction time],[Account Name],

lead([Transaction time ],1,1) OVER (ORDER BY [Account Name])

FROM  [dbo].[acct_details]

this should help you

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. The OP is looking for the row with max transaction_time per account number. Your query isn't even looking for the next transaction time per account number, let alone ordering it by the transaction time! And what's with all the square brackets?

Comment: @Boneist: It's Microsoft contamination, all those square brackets and equating `SQL` = `MS SQL`  :-)

Comment: @Boneist: is it wrong to follow the square brackets, i am just following how it is their in the database.

Comment: @ Boneist: He has clearly mentioned that he wants latest transactions for each account

Comment: @Looking_for_answers yes, they did. Your answer doesn't give them that, though. And also, they clearly stated that they wanted an answer that would work for Oracle or Teradata. Those square brackets are definitely not in the Oracle SQL syntax, and I'd be willing to be not in Teradata's either.